# Why I don't have to pay gas for listing an NFT on opensea?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, opensea

How can this be done, is it a signed voucher? Any sample code that I can take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until anyone buys the NFT, it does not exist on the blockchain. It's "just" a record in OpenSea's offchain database.

Only when they buy the NFT through OpenSea, the buyser sends a transaction - effectively paying gas fees to mint the NFT.

---

Code example of signing a message and validating with ethers.js

```
const message = "hello";
const [signer] = await ethers.getSigners();
const signature = await signer.signMessage(message);

console.log(
    ethers.utils.verifyMessage(message, signature) == signer.address
);
```

Comment: Dear Petr, thanks for replying. I am trying to implement similar function, do you know where can I find the sample code? Like is that a signed transaction without being broadcasted?

Comment: @happyboy When the author creates the NFT (not yet minted), they don't sign any transaction. They just sign an arbitrary message (given by OpenSea) with their private key, so that OpenSea is able to validate the request (verify the signature and the original message - and validate against the signer address). Example with `ethers.js`, here are links to their methods to [sign](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signMessage) a message, and to [verify](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/signing-key/#utils-verifyMessage) the signature... I updated the answer with code example.

Comment: May I further ask one more question? How should I transfer user's WETH without having them signing? I know the Seaport contract get approval in advance. But I am not sure how to trigger that in the smart contract

Comment: @happyboy The token holder always needs to sign the approval transaction - approving your contract  to operate their tokens. Then your contract invoke the `WETH`'s function `transferFrom()` that validates the approval (whether the operator is allowed to operate the sender's tokens) and balance (of the sender), and transfers the tokens.

Comment: May I ask if there is any sample code for validating a signed message in solidity?

Comment: @happyboy You can use the Solidity native function `ecrecover()` ([code example](https://solidity-by-example.org/signature/)) or any of its wrappers, such as OpenZeppelin's ECDSA ([docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/utilities#checking_signatures_on_chain)).